# Laravel join with eloquent

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I have a people table, people can be in many departments.

```
public function departments()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Departments', 'id');
    }
```

I have a departments table, a department has many people

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\People', 'id', 'department_id');
```

**The people table**

```
-id 
-name
-title
```

**The departments table**

```
-id
-person_id
-department_id
```

**The person_id is the foreign key.**

So if I am looking to return all the people from departments 2 (accounting) I can do this

```
$depts = $departments::where('department_id', 2)->get();
   foreach($depts as $dept) {
     // do something
   }
```

But this only returns their id. It's a start but how do I do the join to return the name and title? Do I have to do the foreach or is there a way to do a join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whereHas` will constrain the query by a relation:

```
$departmentId = 2;

People::whereHas('departments', function($query) use ($departmentId) {
    return $query->where('id', $departmentId);
})
->get();
```

Comment: That is great! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should get the people, unless I am missing something.

```
$department = Department::with(['people'])->find(2);

$people = $department->people;
```